# Recursive association behaves differently in index/show/edit actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use recursive association in Ruby on Rails and I'm not getting the expected output :) I want to have match with two players (winner and loser) and I thought about recursive association.

I used scaffolds to get the basics done:

```
rails g scaffold Player firstname:string lastname:string
rails g scaffold Match date:date result:integer winner:references loser:references
```

And then modified Match model:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :winner, class_name: 'Player', foreign_key: 'id'
  has_one :loser, class_name: 'Player', foreign_key: 'id'
end
```

However if I add manually some players and go to match#index both winner and loser are the same (even if I set them to be different).

Part of view is like this:

```
<tbody>
 <% @matches.each do |match| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= match.date %></td>
    <td><%= match.result %></td>
    <td><%= match.winner %></td>
    <td><%= match.loser %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', match %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_match_path(match) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', match, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

When I edit Match, then I clearly see that there are different IDs of players, but in show or index both players are the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an "[has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association)" association, which is actually setting the database link on the other class/table (here, Player). This is not what you want: you want to have two foreign keys (winner_id and loser_id) on the Match table.

This can be done using the much more common "[belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association)" association:

```
class Match  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :winner, class_name: "Player"
  belongs_to :loser, class_name: "Player"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I copied your solution, but it totally stops showing player names (I have def to_s "#{firstname} #{lastname}". If I put belongs_to :winner, class_name: "Player", foreign_key: 'id'  then it again shows winner and loser as the same person :(

Comment: You could try with foreign_key: "winner_id" and foreign_key: "loser_id" respectively

Comment: belongs_to + foreign key change was my problem, thank you very much! :)